# Can not rewrite slash rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, url-rewriting, slash

I need to add code in the htaccess to open my page from `site.com/page` and `site.com/page/` to open the same page. There are many codes for this but it won't work for me because I already have a code for it to remove .html ending so far I have this.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

What can I add to this code to also rewrite if opened with extra slash?

This is the Full htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    </IfModule>

    ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

    <IfModule deflate_module>
        # Enable compression for the following file types.
        AddOutputFilterByType            \
         DEFLATE                         \
          application/javascript         \
          text/css                       \
          text/html                      \
          text/javascript                \
          text/plain                     \
          text/xml
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey it didn't work I put that in and still error 404 when I open website.com/page/

Comment: You put that. But only that ?

Comment: What do you mean only that?  I replaced the code above with what you wrote

Comment: Nothing else in the `.htaccess` ? Because it must work If the `page.html` file exists...

Comment: I do have more but I didn't think it was necessary I edited my post please look.